# Jenkins RequireJs Build / CI

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, requirejs, gradle

I've just started a project that uses RequireJs, Backbone etc. Everything is running well client-side and I wan't to set up my build environment.

I was planning on using Jenkins but have found zero information on how to go about this. I've managed to set up Gradle and use that to do things like minify the js etc, but I think I need to run R.js and have no idea where to get started or if this is even what I should be doing.

I've googled a bunch and found nothing. Sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has a Gradle plugin: [Gradle Jenkins Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin)

### Installation

The plugin is very easy to install and use. To install it, just use the Jenkins web interface.

> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Available Plugins -> Install

Search for Gradle, check the box and click install.

### Create a job

Click new job. Select free style job and add a Gradle build step.